# MySQL Character Set & Select Query Performance in stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql

Recently I noticed few queries are taking very long time in execution, checked further and found that MySQL Optimizer is trying to use COLLATE in `Where` clause and that's causing performance issue, if I run below query without COLLATE then getting quick response from database:

```
 SELECT notification_id FROM notification  
    WHERE ref_table = 2 
    AND ref_id =  NAME_CONST('v_wall_detail_id',_utf8mb4'c37e32fc-b3b5-11ec-befc-02447a44a47c' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

MySQL version 5.7

```
Database Character Set: utf8mb4
Column Character set: UTF8 
Column Data Type: CHAR(36) UUID
From PHP in Connection object passing: utf8mb4
Index is applied

This query is written in MySQL stored procedure
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `notification` (
  `notification_id` CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,    
  `title` VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';

```
collation_connection  utf8_general_ci                                 
collation_database   utf8mb4_unicode_ci                               
collation_server      latin1_swedish_ci
```

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';

```
character_set_client, Connection,Result, System:   utf8
character_set_database      utf8mb4 
character_set_server       latin1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
character_set_system       utf8
```

Any suggestion, what improvements are needed to make my queries faster?

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life next year. I would consider upgrading.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks for prompt reply, do you think upgrade will solve my problem? was there such known bug in 5.7?

Comment: My guess is that it won't fix it (but I'm not sure). What I was trying to convey is that support for this version will start to dwindle soon and bug won't be fixed.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`.

Comment: @RickJames Added output of requested variable in question description. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The table's character set is utf8, so I guess its collation is one of utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci. You can check this way:

```
SELECT collation_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = '...your schema...' AND table_name = 'notification'
  AND column_name = 'ref_id';
```

You are forcing it to compare to a string with a utf8mb4 charset and collation. An index is a sorted data structure, and the sort order depends on the collation of the column. Using that index means taking advantage of the sort order to look up values rapidly, without examining every row.

When you compared the column to a string with a different collation, MySQL cannot infer that the sort order or string equivalence of your UUID constant is compatible. So it must do string comparison the hard way, row by row.

This is not a bug, this is the intended way for collations to work. To take advantage of the index, you must compare to a string with a compatible collation.

---

I tested and found that the following expressions fail to use the index:

Different character set, different collation:

```
WHERE ref_id = _utf8mb4'c37e32fc-b3b5-11ec-befc-02447a44a47c' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci

WHERE ref_id = _utf8mb4'c37e32fc-b3b5-11ec-befc-02447a44a47c' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Same character set, different collation:

```
WHERE ref_id = _utf8'c37e32fc-b3b5-11ec-befc-02447a44a47c' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

---

The following expressions successfully use the index:

Different character set, default collation:

```
WHERE ref_id = _utf8mb4'c37e32fc-b3b5-11ec-befc-02447a44a47c'
```

Same character set, same collation:

```
WHERE ref_id = _utf8'c37e32fc-b3b5-11ec-befc-02447a44a47c' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
```

Same character set, default collation:

```
WHERE ref_id = _utf8'c37e32fc-b3b5-11ec-befc-02447a44a47c'
```

---

To simplify your environment, I recommend you should just use one character set and one collation in all tables and in your session. I suggest:

```
ALTER TABLE notification CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This will rebuild the indexes on string columns, using the sort order for the specified collation.

Then using `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` will be compatible, and will use the index.

P.S. In all cases I omitted the NAME_CONST() function, because it has no purpose in a WHERE clause as far as I know. I don't know why you are using it.

Comment: Thanks @bill-karwin for detail reply NAME_CONST is not written in my Query but SQL analyzer is trying to build query which contains NAME_CONST. My query in SP is ref_id = v_wall_detail_id

Answer (score 1):

These say what the client is talking in:

```
collation_connection  utf8_general_ci
character_set_client, Connection,Result, System:   utf8
```

Either change them or change the various columns to match them.

If you have Stored routines, they need to be dropped, do `SET NAMES` to match what you picked, then re-CREATEd.

Since you are using 5.7, I recommend using `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` throughout.